# Square root of $M‎_{‎\varphi‎}:‎L‎^{2}[0,1]‎\to‎L‎^2[0,1]‎$,‎ ‎$‎M‎_{‎\varphi}(f)= ‎\varphi f$‎

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let ‎$\varphi ‎\in ‎C[0,‎ ‎1]‎$‎.
Define $M‎_{‎\varphi‎}:‎L‎^{2}[0,1]‎‎‎\to‎L‎^2[0,1]‎$,‎ ‎$‎M‎_{‎\varphi}(f)= ‎\varphi f$‎‎.‎
It ‎seems ‎that $ M‎_{‎\varphi}$‎ ‎is a‎ ‎linear ‎bounded ‎operator.‎

**Questions**

1. Is‎ ‎$ ‎M‎_{‎\varphi} ‎\geq ‎0‎$ ‎if ‎only ‎if ‎ $ ‎\varphi‎ ‎\ge ‎0‎‎$‎?
2. What ‎is ‎the ‎square ‎root ‎of ‎‎$‎M‎_{‎\varphi}‎$‎?
3. I‎ ‎think ‎that‎ $T$ ‎is ‎normal, ‎is ‎it ‎right?

Comment: What is the adjoint of $M‎_{‎\varphi} $? What is its spectrum? These are both easy to answer, and will help answer your questions.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The map $\varphi \mapsto M_{\varphi}$ from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathcal{B}(L^2[0,1])$ is an homomorphism of $C^{*}$-algebras whose image lies in the collection of normal operators. It preserves positive elements and assuming $\varphi \geq 0$, (a) square root of $M_{\varphi}$ is the operator $M_{\sqrt{\varphi}}$.